# Accessing child elements in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to access this html element which has an id dynamically set by `attr:{id:}`

```
<script type="text/html" id="comment">
    <td class="dock-panel-parent">
        <a data-bind="attr:{id: 'commentIcon' + $context.cellContext.status.rowIndex}, click: $parent.toggleCommentSelection" class="fa fa-plus" style="float: right"> </a> 
     </td>
</script>
```

I am trying to trigger this click event from another function but am unable to even access the id of this element from anywhere outside my toggleCommentSelection event

```
    self.handleOkResponse = function () {
        var currentId = self.currentEvent().currentTarget.id;
        var currentIndex;


        currentIndex = currentId.replace(/\D/g,'');
        currentId = 'commentIcon' + currentIndex;

         $('#' + currentId).trigger("click"); 
    };
```

I checked that the id is correct, but it doesn't seem like I am able to access it being that it's nested. Is there a way I can alter the properties of this from another parent function not bound to the element?

Answer (score 0):

In parent viewmodel, store the this pointer.

```
var self = this;
```

Then in the construction of child object pass the self as a parameter

```
   self.addFormMenu = function(item) {
    var i;
    self.formMenu([]);
    for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      self.formMenu.push(new VisFormMenuVm(item[i], self));
    }
    self.activeFormPage(1);
  };
```

Store that self pointer in the child.

```
 var VisFormMenuVm = function(data, myparent) {
    'use strict';
    var self = this;
    self.parent = myparent;
```

Then you should be able to do actions on parent from child.

```
self.parent.searchInput("");
```

To access an object from anywhere in you viewmodel setup, you can do an absolute path to it.  If your binding is like this.

```
viewModel = {

  visualization : new VisualizationVm([], "summary"),
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You can call this from anywhere in your javascript and navigate all of the child objects to the one you want to modify.

```
viewModel.visualization.topicbuilder().aceEditor.getSession().setMode({
        path : "ace/mode/xml",
        v : Date.now()
      });
```

Comment: Isn't the child in this case my <a> element? I'm already able to manipulate the id from my toggleCommentSelection function which is bound on the click. I need to do actions on the child id attribute from the parent, which is the context of my handleOkResponse function. Unless I'm misunderstanding the lingo here.

Comment: Added a section on accessing from anywhere at bottom of solution.